# Order by in mysql without asc and desc

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a table 'book_history' with a field 'status'

```
So there are three values for the field 'status' => 0,1,2
```

Now i want to query it in orderby - I know order by asc and order by desc is there.
But how i really want is

```
select * from book_history order by status 1,0,2
```

I checked with order by then also. But I was not able to make my query.

So the final output will be - first it should list the status=1, then status=0 and then status='2'

Any help.

Thanks,

Kimz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [*FIELD()*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  book_history 
ORDER BY FIELD(`status`, 1, 0, 2)
```

Comment: khalid - thanks .. just now marked your answer as accepted one again.. thanks again for your help

Answer (score 3):

Use below query to force order in query:

```
select * from book_history 
ORDER BY FIELD (status,1,0,2);
```

For more information if there is more values and you keep your values on top and rest values after that then you can use below query:

```
select * from book_history 
ORDER BY FIELD (status,2,0,1) desc;
```

Comment: @RakeshSharma first of all when I was updating my answer there was no answer for this query...anyway are you seeing any other answer same as me..

Comment: @RakeshSharma: I guess this answer differs from M Khalid Junaid's answer.

Comment: @ZafarMalik desc won't give the desired result set [*see demo*](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82119/1) and  [*with desc*](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82119/2)

Comment: @user3350885 even this is your choice but accepted answer should be of M Khalid Junaid as he provided solution earlier than me and even any other... it is just my view ):

Answer (score 2):

You can use ORDER BY FIELD:

```
SELECT * FROM book_history ORDER BY FIELD(status, 1,0,2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a case expression to get an order key:

```
select * 
from book_history 
order by 
  case status 
    when 1 then 100 -- any small value would do here
    when 0 then 200 -- any medium value would do here
    when 2 then 300 -- any big value would do here
  end;
```

Comment: This is Standard SQL and should work in almost all dbms. M Khalid Junaid's answer using FIELD() is MySQL specific. I would use his solution for readability rather than mine. (If you don't happen to be forced to use standard SQL only for some reason this is).

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative with `UNION`:

```
select * from book_history where status = 1
UNION
select * from book_history where status = 0
UNION
select * from book_history where status = 2
```

Comment: You should use **UNION ALL** when there are obviously no duplicates to be removed. However, UNION and even UNION ALL do not guarantee to keep the order. You would still need an ORDER BY clause to guarantee to get the results ordered.